# how to inform the community about new entries of a specific taxonomy

Tags: rules

In my content type article there is a taxonomy field called "`field_article_city`".
In the user profile is the taxonomy field called "`field_profile_city`".

Now i want to create a rule, that informs all users with the same taxonomy "`field_profile_city`" when new content is created from the equal city "`field_article_city`".

I tried the condition "data comparison" to match these fields together, but there is no convenient selector for the users. i need a selector like "`site:users`" but there is only "`site:current-user`" or "`node:author`". But this wont work.

Someone can help me?